# Changes to skin in SDK path not taking effect?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5, flex4.6

I'm using the SparkChromeWindowedApplicationSkin in my Window Application and I'm making changes to the skin in the SDK directory but none of my changes are taking effect.

I set the skin in my CSS like this:

```
s|WindowedApplication
{
    backgroundAlpha: 1;
    backgroundColor: #FFFFFF;
    resizeAffordanceWidth: 6;
    skinClass: ClassReference("spark.skins.spark.SparkChromeWindowedApplicationSkin");
}
```

Then I control + click on the skin name and it opens the file. I then change some of the styles and properties. I then run the application. None of my changes seem to make a difference.

**UPDATE**:  I just typed random gibberish into the skin and no errors were thrown. So I know it's not using the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied the skins out of the SDK directory and placed them into my project folder. I placed them the same package / folder path as they had in the SDK and copied the assets to the root of my project folder (same path again). This worked! I'm still curious to know if this is the way everyone else does it and why the changes to the skins in the SDK did not update with my changes. Here is a screenshot of my project src directory now:

[image: Screenshot of my project]